# html5 web app manifest boilerplate?

Tags: html, web-applications, manifest, boilerplate

Is there a boilerplate for html5 web apps?

Safari for example, has specific guidelines on manifests in order to make a web site into an app, Firefox also has similar guidelines, as does chrome.

Is there any boilerplate for quickly starting an html5 webapp?

Comment: Check this site, I've used it a lot: http://www.initializr.com/

Comment: that's really cool, but and it does pretty much everything BUT manifests -- my main concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Google's Web Starter Kit: https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/blob/master/app/manifest.json

There's also a generator at: https://tomitm.github.io/appmanifest/

There's also a validator at: http://manifest-validator.appspot.com/

Answer (score -1):

https://html5boilerplate.com

> Mobile Boilerplate helps you create rich, performant, and modern
>   mobile web apps. Kick-start your project with dozens of mobile
>   optimizations and helpers.